# sentry not logging errors faraday timeout

Tags: timeout, sentry

I have a sentry instance setup with with `celery` and `redis`. All the projects are able to log events fine except for two particular projects under the same team. It exits out with the following error `Unable to record event with remote Sentry server (Faraday::TimeoutError - execution expired)`

That error starts to appear after sometime, initially the exceptions are caught, and logged by `sentry` any ideas why?